# On the equation $y^2 = x^3 - z^3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

What is the parametric form of the rational solutions of the equation $y^2 = x^3 - z^3 ?$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414088/i-want-to-find-all-the-rational-solutions-of-x2y3-z3/2414213#2414213

Comment: Hello @PRIMES is in P., and welcome to MO. Please have a look at https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic . Mathoverflow is a website for questions about research level mathematics. As pointed out in individ 's comment, this question as already been asked (and answered) on MSE.

Answer (score 11):

This may be (probably is) too elementary for this site, it would be better on MathStackExchange. But the basic idea is to make a change of variables to simplify. (In fancy algebraic geometry terms, it's blowing up a singularity.) In this case, let
$$ x = y u \quad\text{and}\quad z = y v. $$
Then your equation becomes
$$ y^{-1} = u^3-v^3, $$
so you get the parametrization
$$ x = \frac{u}{u^3-v^3},\quad y=\frac{1}{u^3-v^3},\quad z=\frac{v}{u^3-v^3}. $$
This gives a rational solution for all $u,v\in\mathbb Q$ with $u\ne v$. And conversely, (almost) every rational solution gives a unique $u,v$ value.